# How to start XAMPP-VM by command line?

Tags: xampp-vm

I'm using [image]

I need to write a shell script to automatically start XAMPP-VM, Apache, and MySQL.

How can I start XAMPP-VM by a command line?

Answer (score 0):

View /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/ctlscript.sh, you could see all logic of scripts which control XAMPP's services by shell script.